# Parallel Haskell in order to find the divisors of a huge number

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I have written the following program using Parallel Haskell to find the divisors of 1 billion.

```
import Control.Parallel

parfindDivisors :: Integer->[Integer]
parfindDivisors n = f1 `par` (f2 `par` (f1 ++ f2))
              where f1=filter g [1..(quot n 4)]
                    f2=filter g [(quot n 4)+1..(quot n 2)]
                    g z = n `rem` z == 0

main = print (parfindDivisors 1000000000)
```

I've compiled the program with `ghc -rtsopts -threaded findDivisors.hs` and I run it with:
`findDivisors.exe +RTS -s -N2 -RTS`

I have found a 50% speedup compared to the simple version which is this:

```
findDivisors :: Integer->[Integer]
findDivisors n = filter g [1..(quot n 2)] 
      where  g z = n `rem` z == 0
```

My processor is a dual core 2 duo from Intel.
I was wondering if there can be any improvement in above code. Because in the statistics that program prints says:
`Parallel GC work balance: 1.01 (16940708 / 16772868, ideal 2)`
and `SPARKS: 2 (1 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 1 fizzled)`
What are these **converted** , **overflowed** , **dud**, **GC'd**, **fizzled** and how can help to improve the time.

Comment: An improvement of my code in terms of load balancing is here [link](http://pastie.org/4746931)

Comment: it should be `f1 \`par\` f2 \`pseq\` (f1 ++ f2)`

Comment: Of course, using a better algorithm would give you lower complexity. Are you only interested in improving the parallelism, or also in a better algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the `Par` monad helps for reasoning about parallelism.  It's a little higher-level than dealing with `par` and `pseq`.

Here's a rewrite of `parfindDivisors` using the `Par` monad.  Note that this is essentially the same as your algorithm:

```
import Control.Monad.Par

findDivisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
findDivisors n = runPar $ do
    [f0, f1] <- sequence [new, new]
    fork $ put f0 (filter g [1..(quot n 4)])
    fork $ put f1 (filter g [(quot n 4)+1..(quot n 2)])
    [f0', f1'] <- sequence [get f0, get f1]
    return $ f0' ++ f1'
  where g z  = n `rem` z == 0
```

Compiling that with `-O2 -threaded -rtsopts -eventlog` and running with `+RTS -N2 -s` yields the following relevant runtime stats:

```
  36,000,130,784 bytes allocated in the heap
       3,165,440 bytes copied during GC
          48,464 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     35162 colls, 35161 par    0.39s    0.32s     0.0000s    0.0006s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     1 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0002s    0.0002s

  Parallel GC work balance: 1.32 (205296 / 155521, ideal 2)

  MUT     time   42.68s  ( 21.48s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.39s  (  0.32s elapsed)
  Total   time   43.07s  ( 21.80s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    843,407,880 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.1% of total user, 195.8% of total elapsed
```

The productivity is very high.  To improve the GC work balance slightly we can increase the GC allocation area size; run with `+RTS -N2 -s -A128M`, for example:

```
  36,000,131,336 bytes allocated in the heap
          47,088 bytes copied during GC
          49,808 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       135 colls,   134 par    0.19s    0.10s     0.0007s    0.0009s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     1 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0010s    0.0010s

  Parallel GC work balance: 1.62 (2918 / 1801, ideal 2)

  MUT     time   42.65s  ( 21.49s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.20s  (  0.10s elapsed)
  Total   time   42.85s  ( 21.59s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    843,925,806 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.5% of total user, 197.5% of total elapsed
```

But this is really just nitpicking.  The real story comes from ThreadScope:

[image: lots of utilisation]

The utilisation is essentially maxed out for two cores, so additional significant parallelization (for two cores) is probably not going to happen.

Some good notes on the `Par` monad are [here](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/slides/CUFP.pdf).

**UPDATE**

A rewrite of the alternative algorithm using `Par` looks something like this:

```
findDivisors ::  Integer -> [Integer]
findDivisors n = let sqrtn = floor (sqrt (fromInteger n)) in runPar $ do
    [a, b] <- sequence [new, new]
    fork $ put a [a | (a, b) <- [quotRem n x | x <- [1..sqrtn]], b == 0]
    firstDivs  <- get a
    fork $ put b [n `quot` x | x <- firstDivs, x /= sqrtn]
    secondDivs <- get b
    return $ firstDivs ++ secondDivs
```

But you're right in that this will not get any gains from parallelism due to the dependence on `firstDivs`.

You can still incorporate parallelism here, by getting `Strategies` involved to evaluate the elements of the list comprehensions in parallel.  Something like:

```
import Control.Monad.Par
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

findDivisors ::  Integer -> [Integer]
findDivisors n = let sqrtn = floor (sqrt (fromInteger n)) in runPar $ do
    [a, b] <- sequence [new, new]
    fork $ put a 
        ([a | (a, b) <- [quotRem n x | x <- [1..sqrtn]], b == 0] `using` parListChunk 2 rdeepseq)
    firstDivs  <- get a
    fork $ put b 
        ([n `quot` x | x <- firstDivs, x /= sqrtn] `using` parListChunk 2 rdeepseq)
    secondDivs <- get b
    return $ firstDivs ++ secondDivs
```

and running this gives some stats like

```
       3,388,800 bytes allocated in the heap
          43,656 bytes copied during GC
          68,032 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         5 colls,     4 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0000s    0.0001s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     1 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0002s    0.0002s

  Parallel GC work balance: 1.22 (2800 / 2290, ideal 2)

                        MUT time (elapsed)       GC time  (elapsed)
  Task  0 (worker) :    0.01s    (  0.01s)       0.00s    (  0.00s)
  Task  1 (worker) :    0.01s    (  0.01s)       0.00s    (  0.00s)
  Task  2 (bound)  :    0.01s    (  0.01s)       0.00s    (  0.00s)
  Task  3 (worker) :    0.01s    (  0.01s)       0.00s    (  0.00s)

  SPARKS: 50 (49 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 1 fizzled)

  MUT     time    0.01s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.01s  (  0.01s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    501,672,834 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  85.0% of total user, 95.2% of total elapsed
```

Here almost 50 sparks were converted - that is, meaningful parallel work was being done - but the computations were not large enough to observe any wall-clock gains from parallelism.  Any gains were probably offset by the overhead of scheduling computations in the threaded runtime.

Comment: For the record, changing the `Integer` types to `Int` is probably the quickest/easiest optimization to make in the case of a billion.

Comment: How can I use a list comprehension with Control.Monad.Par?

Comment: Just replace the calls to filter in `put` with the list comprehension you want.  I.e. `fork $ put f0 [x | x <- [1..(quot n 4)], g x]`.

Comment: I want to feed the list comprehension with a list that has been "put" in the monad. But the left arrow operator which is used to extract something from a monad it has other meaning when it is in the context of a list comprehension. Please see my answer and tell me if this answer can be used with Monad.Par

Answer (score 1):

I think this page explains it better than I could:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ThreadScope_Tour/SparkOverview

I also found these slides interesting:

http://haskellwiki.gitit.net/Upload/HIW2011-Talk-Coutts.pdf

Answer (score 0):

My modifying the original code with the following I have better speedup but this code I think that cannot be parallelised

```
findDivisors2 :: Integer->[Integer]
findDivisors2 n= let firstDivs=[a|(a,b)<-[quotRem n x|x<-[1..sqrtn]],b==0]
                 secondDivs=[n `quot` x|x<-firstDivs,x/=sqrtn]
                 sqrtn = floor(sqrt (fromInteger n))
               in firstDivs ++ secondDivs
```

I tried to parallelise the code with this:

```
parfindDivisors2 :: Integer->[Integer]
parfindDivisors2 n= let firstDivs=[a|(a,b)<-[quotRem n x|x<-[1..sqrtn]],b==0]
                 secondDivs=[n `quot` x|x<-firstDivs,x/=sqrtn]
                 sqrtn = floor(sqrt (fromInteger n))
               in  secondDivs `par` firstDivs++secondDivs
```

Instead of reducing the time I have doubled the time. I think that this happens because the findDivisors2 have **strong** data dependence while the first algorithm `findDivisors` does not.

Any comments are welcome.